# Form validation not working for multi step form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to make a multi step form with validation. The multi step buttons are working and I'm able to submit the form but the form is not getting validated. It validates only the last page in the multistep form but I want to validate fields before I press 'next' button everytime.

The Html code:

```
<form name="basicform" id="basicform" method="post" 
action="yourpage.html">

<!-- id will be unique, but class name will be same -->
<div id="sf1" class="frm">
<fieldset>
        <legend>Step 1 of 3</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="uname">Your Name: 
 </label>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" id="uname" 
 name="uname" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <!-- open1 is given in the class that is binded with the 
 click event -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary open1" type="button">Next 
 <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button> 
          </div>
        </div>

</fieldset>
</div>

<!-- id will be unique, but class name will be same -->
<div id="sf2" class="frm">
<fieldset>
        <legend>Step 2 of 3</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="uemail">Your 
 Email: </label>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email" id="uemail" 
 name="uemail" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px;clear: both;"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <!-- back2 unique class name  -->
            <button class="btn btn-warning back2" type="button"><span 
class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Back</button> 
            <!-- open2 unique class name -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary open2" type="button">Next 
<span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button> 
          </div>
        </div>
</fieldset>
</div>

<!-- id will be unique, but class name will be same -->
<div id="sf3" class="frm">
<fieldset>
        <legend>Step 3 of 3</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="upass1">Password: 
 </label>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" 
 id="upass1" name="upass1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="upass1">Confirm 
 Password: </label>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" 
 id="upass2" name="upass2" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <!-- Unique class name -->
            <button class="btn btn-warning back3" type="button"><span 
class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Back</button> 
            <!-- Unique class name -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary open3" type="button">Submit 
</button> 
            <img src="spinner.gif" alt="" id="loader" style="display: 
none">
          </div>
        </div>
</fieldset>
</div>

</form>
```

JavaScript/Jquery Code:

```
//validation
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function() {

var v = jQuery("#basicform").validate({
  rules: {
    uname: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 16
    },
    uemail: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2,
      email: true,
      maxlength: 100,
    },
    upass1: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
        maxlength: 15,
    },
    upass2: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
      equalTo: "#upass1",
    }

  },
  errorElement: "span",
  errorClass: "help-inline",
});

});

//navigation
jQuery().ready(function() {

// Binding next button on first step
$(".open1").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#sf2").show("slow");
  }
});

// Binding next button on second step
$(".open2").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#sf3").show("slow");
  }
});

 // Binding back button on second step
$(".back2").click(function() {
  $(".frm").hide("fast");
  $("#sf1").show("slow");
});

 // Binding back button on third step
 $(".back3").click(function() {
  $(".frm").hide("fast");
  $("#sf2").show("slow");
});

$(".open3").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    // optional
    // used delay form submission for a seccond and show a loader 
image
    $("#loader").show();
     setTimeout(function(){
       $("#basicform").html('<h2>Thanks for your time.</h2>');
     }, 1000);
    // Remove this if you are not using ajax method for submitting 
values
    return false;
  }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring your form "v" in a separate jQuery().ready block, so "v" isn't being detected by the second jQuery().ready block. Merge them into one block like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var v = $("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
      fname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 16
      },
      lname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        email: true,
        maxlength: 100,
      },
      prnum: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        maxlength: 15,
      },
      age: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
      }
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-inline",
  });


  // Binding next button on first step
  $(".frm").hide("fast");
  $("#sf1").show("slow");

  $(".open1").click(function() {
    if (v.form()) {
      $(".frm").hide("fast");
      $("#sf2").show("slow");
    }
  });

  // Binding next button on second step
  $(".open2").click(function() {
    if (v.form()) {
      $(".frm").hide("fast");
      $("#sf3").show("slow");
    }
  });

  $(".open3").click(function() {
    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#sf4").show("slow");
  });

  // Binding back button on second step
  $(".back2").click(function() {
    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#sf1").show("slow");
  });

  // Binding back button on third step
  $(".back3").click(function() {
    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#sf2").show("slow");
  });

  $(".back4").click(function() {
    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#sf3").show("slow");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="saveDoc.html" method="post">
  <h1 style="color:#000">New Doctor Registration</h1>
  <br>
  <div id="sf1" class="frm">
    <!--  user name field will be here with next button -->
    <fieldset>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <font size="5" color="#009999">Step 1 of 4</font>
      <hr style="border: 1px solid #cccccc">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Doctor Id <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="docID" id="docID" class="form-control input-sm" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Date of Join <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="date" name="doj" id="doj" max="3000-12-31" class="form-control input-sm" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Registration Number<span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="prnum" id="prnum" class="form-control input-sm" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Employment Type <span>*</span></p>
            <select class="form-control" name="etype" id="etype" required>
              <option default selected>Select Employment Type</option>
              <option>Permanent</option>
              <option>Temporary</option>
              <option>Visiting</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Preferred Shift <span>*</span></p>
            <select class="form-control" name="shift" id="shift" required>
              <option default selected>Select Shift</option>
              <option>Morning</option>
              <option>Afternoon</option>
              <option>Evening</option>
              <option>Night</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Department <span>*</span></p>
            <select class="form-control" name="department" id="department">
              <option default selected>Select Department</option>
              <option>Cardiology</option>
              <option>Critical Care</option>
              <option>General Surgery</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <p>Designation <span>*</span></p>
              <select class="form-control" name="designation" id="designation">
                <option default selected>Select Designation</option>
                <option> Doctor of Dental Surgery</option>
                <option>Doctor of Psychology</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
          <!-- open1 is given in the class that is binded with the click event -->
          <center>
            <button class="btn btn-primary open1" name="button1" id="button1" type="button">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <!-- id will be unique, but class name will be same -->
  <div id="sf2" class="frm">
    <!--  user email field will be here with next and previous button -->
    <fieldset>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <font size="5" color="#009999">Step 2 of 4</font>
      <hr style="border: 1px solid #cccccc">
      <center><b><font size="3">Personal Details</font></b></center>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>First Name <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control input-sm" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Middle Name <span></span></p>
            <input type="text" name="mname" id="mname" class="form-control input-sm" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Last Name <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Date of Birth <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" max="3000-12-31" value="2012-05-15 21:05" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Age <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="number" name="age" id="age" maxlength="3" class="form-control input-sm form_datetime" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
              <p>Gender <span>*</span></p>
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 10px;" value="M" type="radio" name="gender" />M</label>
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="radio" value="F" name="gender" />F</label>
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="radio" value="Transgender" name="gender" />Transgender</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>SSN <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="ssn" id="ssn" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px;clear: both;"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
          <!-- back2 unique class name  -->
          <center>
            <button class="btn btn-warning back2" type="button"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Back</button>
            <!-- open2 unique class name -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary open2" type="button">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <!-- id will be unique, but class name will be same -->
  <div id="sf3" class="frm">
    <!--  user email field will be here with next and previous button -->
    <fieldset>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <font size="5" color="#009999">Step 3 of 4</font>
      <hr style="border: 1px solid #cccccc">
      <center><b><font size="3">Contact Details</font></b></center>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>LandPhone <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="landphone" id="landphone" value="080-" maxlength="11" class="form-control input-sm" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Mobile<span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="+91" maxlength="14" class="form-control input-sm" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Email <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" required />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Address1<span>*</span></p>
            <textarea name="address" id="address1" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="address1" required></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Address2<span></span></p>
            <textarea name="address2" id="address2" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="address2"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Country <span>*</span></p>
            <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" required>
              <option>Select Country</option>
              <option>India</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>State <span>*</span></p>
            <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state" required>
              <option>Select State</option>
              <option>Karnataka</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>City <span>*</span></p>
            <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city" required>
              <option>Select City</option>
              <option>Bangalore</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Postal Code<span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="pcode" maxlength="6" id="pcode" class="form-control input-sm" required />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px;clear: both;"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
          <!-- back2 unique class name  -->
          <center>
            <button class="btn btn-warning back3" type="button"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Back</button>
            <!-- open2 unique class name -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary open3" type="button">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div id="sf4" class="frm">
    <!--  user email field will be here with next and previous button -->
    <fieldset>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <font size="5" color="#009999">Step 4 of 4</font>
      <hr style="border: 1px solid #cccccc">
      <center><b><font size="3">Education Details</font></b></center>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Qualification <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="qualification" id="qualification" class="form-control input-sm" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Specialization <span>*</span></p>
            <input type="text" name="specialization" id="specialization" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
          <!-- Unique class name -->
          <center>
            <button class="btn btn-warning back4" type="button"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Back</button>
            <!-- Unique class name -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary open4 ">Save</button>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <!--  <div class="form-group">
            <p>Department <span>*</san></p>
            <select class="form-control" name="dept" id="dept" required>
            <option>Select Department</option>
            <option>OPD</option>
            <option>Cardiology</option>
            <option>Critical Care</option>
            
            </select>
            </div>
            -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="" class="bouton-contact" onclick=""></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But validation is still not working. There appears to be a problem with 'v.form()'. Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Did you try running the above snippet? It prevents you from going to next step until the field is filled out correctly..

Comment: Yeah I tried your snippet but the 'next' button is not working even though all the fields are entered. It works only when 'v.form()' is removed but that time validation doesn't work. Is there any other url to include to make it work?

Comment: Here's my full code. It validates only the last page of the multi-step form. I cant find the problem. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coder33455/27tym9fh/)

Comment: I've updated the snippet and the fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/27tym9fh/3/ so it should now be working. Check for v.form() instead of v.valid() before moving to next steps, since it checks the entire form..